# Move image around circle to a specific point in Xamarin Form PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing one application in Xamarin Form PCL Cross Platform.Here on my landing page,there is one circular menu with 8 menus.What I want is when a user click on any of one menu,the menus should move circular so that the clicked menu should be stop on bottom and open on Page.Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please read the "How to Ask" pages in the Help section.  What you've posted is not a question - it is a list of requirements.

Comment: I have updated my question